# How can I calculate and delete all my application cache

Tags: android, caching, settings

How can I calculate and delete all my application cache as it done by pushing on clean cache in main phone settings menu?

I use such code to calculate application cache

```
File[] files = ArrayUtils.addAll(getCacheDir().listFiles(), getExternalCacheDir().listFiles());
            for (File file : files) {
                size = size + file.length();
            }

private static boolean deleteCash(File directory) {
            if (directory != null && directory.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = directory.list();
                for (String child : children) {
                    if (!deleteCash(new File(directory, child))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return directory.delete();
            } else if (directory != null && directory.isFile()) {
                return directory.delete();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

but this cache size vary greatly from cache size from main settings menu 500kb vs 3Mb.
Why??

Comment: Your calculation is wrong because listFiles won't return contents of subdirectories.  You'd need to write a function like your delete that recursively calculates it.

Comment: Ok, thaks, but why when I'm deleting, in settings remains almost the same size?
Is it any additional directoris which I should added to my list?

Comment: Well you should know where your app writes files i think..